# Calling class functions from another class function with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, class

I have this code here: what I am trying to do is call function 'counterAdder' that lives in class A from the class B.

Then I am supposed to create an instance of A and an instance of B, then call the 'counterAdder' function which updates the instance of A's 'counter' item.

When I run this code, it outputs as 0 but I need 1.

```
class A {
     constructor(){
          this.counter = 0;
     }
}

class B{
     constructor(){
     }
     counterAdder(){
          A.counter +=1;
     }
}

const a = new A();
const b = new B();

b.counterAdder();

console.log(a.counter) // => 1
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get 'a' to update when an action from 'b' is run.

I am unable to modify anything outside of class A and class B and only using pure JavaScript.

Comment: Well, if all you need to do is using ```a```'s function in ```b```, without needing ```a``` to be declared before ```b```, make an instance of ```b```, then an instace of ```a```, pass ```a``` to ```b``` as an argument, and use it inside ```b```. Could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
counterAdder(){
          A.counter +=1;
}
```

does not do what you are trying to do. Instead it adds a new property (or something else, I'm not exactly sure why it even works in the first place). What you want to do is modify the counter of `a`, the variable you assigned to `A`. So instead do this:

```
counterAdder(){
          a.counter +=1;
}
```

Comment: while this does solve the problem. It doesnt solve the true problem. I have two files, one file has class A and the other has class B, when i put the contents of class A into class B file and run it it works, but when they are separate it doesn't work.

I do have `const a = require('./a')` inside the 'b' file and `const b = require('./b')` in the 'a' file

Comment: Are you using `module.exports`?